# Selecting a value from drop down changes the next drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi Guys I am ruby on rails developer and have no idea about javascript or Jquery.

I have a select tag like this :

```
<select name="form[city]" id="form_city">
   <option value="">Select Office</option>
   <option value="WA - Washington PD">WA - Washington PD</option>
   <option value="CA - California PD">CA - California PD</option>
   <option value="NY - NewYork PD">NY - NewYork PD</option>
</select>
```

When a user selects for example ***CA - California PD*** from the above select tag, the next select tag which will be below it should have a drop down list like this :

```
 <select name="form[cityselected]" id="form_cityselected">
   <option value="CAF">CAF</option>
   <option value="CAL">CAL</option>
   <option value="CAU">CAU</option>
   <option value="CAS">CAS</option>
</select>
```

Thus a Javascript or JQuery function has to be used to collect the option selected in "form[city]" and to append F,L,U,S characters to the first two characters from "form[city]" select tag to the second select tag ->  form[cityselected].

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this : http://jsfiddle.net/Q8NW5/

```
$('#form_city').on('change', function (e) {
var val = $(':selected', $(this)).val(),
    val = val.split('-')[0],
    val = val.replace(/\s+/g, ''),
    char = ['F', 'L', 'U', 'S'],
    tpl = '<option val="{val}">{val}</option>',
    html = '';

$(char).each(function (item, value) {
    var opt = val + value;
    html += tpl.replace(/{val}/g, opt);
});

$('#form_cityselected').html(html).show();
$('#form_final_city').show();

var currCity = $('#form_cityselected option:selected').val();
setCity(currCity);

})

$('#form_cityselected').on('change', function () {
    var val = $(':selected', $(this)).val();
    setCity(val);
});

function setCity(city) {
    $('#form_final_city').val(city);
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me thanks, is there a way to display the selected "form_cityselected" in a text field at the end

Comment: I didn't get the question correctly. Is like this something you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/Q8NW5/1/

Comment: Almost there, I need to output the selected second value i.e "form_cityselected" to a text field. 
The one you provided now outputs a label but the problem with that is it doesn't recognize the first selected value of the "form_cityselected" you need to manually select it till it displays on the label

Comment: `<input type="text" value="" name="form[final_city]" id="form_final_city">` is the input tag which should have the second selected value, so that the user can edit it later and save it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but this is the general idea... it's VERY specific to your exact question.

Notice the addition of onSelect in the select html... that's the only html I've changed

```
<select name="form[city]" id="form_city" onSelect="updateOtherSelect(this)">
       <option value="">Select Office</option>
       <option value="WA - Washington PD">WA - Washington PD</option>
       <option value="CA - California PD">CA - California PD</option>
       <option value="NY - NewYork PD">NY - NewYork PD</option>
    </select>

function updateOtherSelect(select){
   //grab just what happens before the first space in your option's value
   var prefix = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value.split(" ")[0];

   //go through all your second drop down values and append, based on the string FLUS (if I understood your question correctly).
   for(i=0; i< document.getItemById("form_cityselected").options.length && i < "FLUS".length; i++){
       document.getItemById("form_cityselected").options[i].value = prefix + "FLUS".charAt(i)
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#form_city').change(function(){
    var cityselectedobj= $('#form_cityselected');
     cityselectedobj.empty()
    var val=$(this).val();
    var text=val.split(' ')[0];
    $('<option>').val(val + 'F').text(text+ 'F').appendTo(cityselectedobj);
    $('<option>').val(val + 'L').text(text+ 'L').appendTo(cityselectedobj);
    $('<option>').val(val + 'U').text(text+ 'U').appendTo(cityselectedobj);
    $('<option>').val(val + 'S').text(text+ 'S').appendTo(cityselectedobj);
)};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x84Kk/1/) here

Comment: you're forgetting to parse out just the chars before the space in his initial value

Answer (score 1):

Below is the example :
I am supposing you know the basics of Jquery .

```
$("#form_city").change(function() {
     // TODO 
filltheVillagecomboBox(villageStrings);//village strings seperatedBy '|'

 });


function filltheVillagecomboBox(villagesStrings){
            if(villagesStrings !=null){
                var villagesStrings = villagesStrings.split('|');

                box.append("<option value='null'>Please select your village</option>");

                for (var i = 0, l = villagesStrings.length-1; i <l; i++){
                    var id =villagesStrings[i].substring(0,2);
                    var village=villagesStrings[i].substring(0,villagesStrings[i].length)
                    $("#form_village").append("<option value="+village+">"+village+"</option>");
            }
            }

            }
```